# Python iteratively rendering docx templates to files

Tags: python, dictionary, docx, python-docx

I'm trying to write a code that will automatically create documentation for me. I'm using python-docx to fill in values in a docx template. I'm having issues with this specific section. I want it to work such that on each word doc the 'DN' value will increase by 1 for however many documents I am producing.

For example if the batch of docs I want was batch 123 and I wanted 4 separate copies of this document, I would want the following from 'DN':

123-1,
123-2,
123-3,
123-4,

instead I'm getting the following:

123-1,
123-1,
123-1,
123-1,

This code works fine for the part at the bottom for saving the file name, it is just an issue with the dictionary section. If someone could suggest a way to make this work it would be very much appreciated.

```
for i in range(0, int(number_of_docs)):
    Enters = {
        'DN': f'{doc_number}-{+i + 1}',
        'Quantity': number_of_docs,
        'Date': date,
             }

    PN_doc.render(Enters)
    PN_doc.save(f"{doc_number}-{+i + 1}.docx")
```

Comment: Not sure what PN_doc.render is doing but I guess your problem must be in there. The composition of the Enters object works okay.. What are you doing in PN_doc.render() ?  Maybe you should make a new PN_doc for each iteration?

Comment: guessing from the syntax you're using python-docx template ?

Comment: Hi Iwohlhart, you're correct I'm using dozx template, probably should have mentioned that

Answer (score 0):

So the Object composition should work the way you implemented it.
For the document: ( maybe there's a neat way to copy the template - I'm not aware of any ).
Just instantiating it for each iteration should also do the job

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

# number_of_docs = ...
# doc_number = ...
# date = ...

for i in range(int(number_of_docs)):
    Enters = {
        "DN": f"{doc_number}-{i+1}",
        "Quantity": number_of_docs,
        "Date": date
    }
    PN_doc = DocxTemplate("your_template.docx")
    PN_doc.render(Enters)
    PN_doc.save(f"{doc_number}-{i+1}.docx")
```